# Knapsacks problem 1/0 dynamic

Tags: c, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I want to solve the knapsack problem with dynamic programming! The item should be in the knapsack or not, I do not want to put the same item in the knapsack more then one time!

I've looked at this code but with this one you can add the same object more then just one time

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXWEIGHT 100

int n = 3; /* The number of objects */
int c[10] = {8, 6, 4}; /* c[i] is the *COST* of the ith object; i.e. what
                YOU PAY to take the object */
int v[10] = {16, 10, 7}; /* v[i] is the *VALUE* of the ith object; i.e.
                what YOU GET for taking the object */
int W = 10; /* The maximum weight you can take */ 

void fill_sack() {
    int a[MAXWEIGHT]; /* a[i] holds the maximum value that can be obtained
                using at most i weight */
    int last_added[MAXWEIGHT]; /* I use this to calculate which object were
                    added */
    int i, j;
    int aux;

    for (i = 0; i <= W; ++i) {
        a[i] = 0;
        last_added[i] = -1;
    }

    a[0] = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= W; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            if ((c[j] <= i) && (a[i] < a[i - c[j]] + v[j])) {
                a[i] = a[i - c[j]] + v[j];
                last_added[i] = j;
            }

    for (i = 0; i <= W; ++i)
        if (last_added[i] != -1)
            printf("Weight %d; Benefit: %d; To reach this weight I added object %d (%d$ %dKg) to weight %d.\n", 
                         i, a[i], last_added[i] + 1, v[last_added[i]], 
                         c[last_added[i]], i - c[last_added[i]]);
        else
            printf("Weight %d; Benefit: 0; Can't reach this exact weight.\n", i);

    printf("---\n");

    aux = W;
    while ((aux > 0) && (last_added[aux] != -1)) {
        printf("Added object %d (%d$ %dKg). Space left: %d\n", 
               last_added[aux] + 1, v[last_added[aux]], 
               c[last_added[aux]], aux - c[last_added[aux]]);
        aux -= c[last_added[aux]];
    }

    printf("Total value added: %d$\n", a[W]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fill_sack();

    return 0;
}
```

and then i tried to make a array to see if the object is in the knapsack or not, but then this program did not work as it should!

```
#define MAXWEIGHT 101
#define MAX_ITEMS 100000

int items = 2;
int c[10] = {1, 2};
int v[10] = {1000, 2001};
int W = 100;
int taken[MAX_ITEMS];

void takenOrNot(){
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < items; i++){
    taken[i] = 0;
  }
}
void fill_sack() {
  int a[MAXWEIGHT];
  int last_added[MAXWEIGHT];
  int i, j;
  int aux;

  for (i = 0; i <= W; ++i) {
    a[i] = 0;
    last_added[i] = -1;
  }

  a[0] = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= W; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < items; ++j)
        if ((c[j] <= i) && (a[i] < a[i - c[j]] + v[j]) && taken[j] == 0) {
            a[i] = a[i - c[j]] + v[j];
            last_added[i] = j;
            taken[j] = 1;
        }

  for (i = 0; i <= W; ++i)
    if (last_added[i] != -1)
      printf("Weight %d; Benefit: %d; To reach this weight I added object %d (%d$ %dKg) to weight %d.\n", 
           i, a[i], last_added[i] + 1, v[last_added[i]], 
           c[last_added[i]], i - c[last_added[i]]);
    else
      printf("Weight %d; Benefit: 0; Can't reach this exact weight.\n", i);

  printf("---\n");

  aux = W;
  while ((aux > 0) && (last_added[aux] != -1)) {
    printf("Added object %d (%d$ %dKg). Space left: %d\n", 
        last_added[aux] + 1, v[last_added[aux]], 
        c[last_added[aux]], aux - c[last_added[aux]]);
    aux -= c[last_added[aux]];
  }

  printf("Total value added: %d$\n", a[W]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  takenOrNot();
  fill_sack();

  return 0;
}
```

Could you guys help me please? :)

Comment: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4802 that is the code I use

Comment: @FredrichP: Why are you using pastie? Why don't you just post it here and highlight it as code as part of your question?

Comment: I coulden't post it here so I did it on pastie..

Comment: " did not work as it should!"... you might want to clarify that. What do you expect? What does/doesn't it do? Etc.

Comment: you want knapsack solution for problem with repeated item or without repeated item.

Answer (score 0):

This might help...!

```
public class Knapsack
{
    int knapsackSize;
    int[] _weights;
    int[] _values;
    int[,] results;


    public Knapsack(int[] weights, int[] values, int size)
    {
        _weights = weights;
        _values = values;
        knapsackSize = size;
    }

    public int CreateSolution()
    {
        results = new int[_weights.Length + 1, knapsackSize + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < _weights.Length; i++)   // item 1 to n
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= knapsackSize; j++) //weight 1 to m
            {
                if (_weights[i] > j)
                {
                    //if item weight is grater than knapsack capacity
                    results[i + 1, j] = results[i, j];
                }

                else
                {
                    if (results[i, j] > (_values[i] + results[i, j - _weights[i]]))
                    {
                        //if previously calculated value only is grater
                        results[i + 1, j] = results[i, j];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //if including current item gives more value
                        results[i + 1, j] = _values[i] + results[i, j - _weights[i]];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return results[_weights.Length, knapsackSize]; // index (n, m) will be max value
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Knapsack demo = new Knapsack(new int[] { 23, 26, 20, 18, 32, 27, 29, 26, 30, 27 }, new int[] { 505, 352, 458, 220, 354, 414, 498, 545, 473, 543 }, 67);
        Console.WriteLine("Solution is: " + demo.CreateSolution());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```